# What can I do if an application is "Not Responding"?

Tags: activity-monitor

An application is reported as "Not Responding" by the activity monitor and "sleeping" by `top`.  I am very reluctant to kill it because I will lose my work.

Is there anything I could do?

E.g., `kill -s SIGINT` - might it help? Is it safe to try?

Comment: This might be easier to answer if you would add the name of the application.

Comment: @patrix: the application is gnu emacs